# I have a large data set where the rows are a series of coordinates and need to plot specific rows

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, coordinates

I have a very large dataset of coordinates that I need plot and specify specific rows instead of just editing the raw excel file.

The data is organized as so

```
   frames      xsnout      ysnout        xMLA        yMLA 
0           532.732971  503.774200  617.231018  492.803711     
1           532.472351  504.891632  617.638550  493.078583    
2           532.453552  505.676300  615.956116  493.2839  
3           532.356079  505.914642  616.226318  494.179047  
4           532.360718  506.818054  615.836548  495.555298
```

The column "frames" is the specific video frame for each of these coordinates (xsnout,ysnout) (xMLA,yMLA). Below is my code which is able to plot all frames and all data points without specifying the row

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#import data
df = pd.read_excel("E:\\Clark\\Flow Tank\\Respirometry\\Cropped_videos\\F1\\MG\\F1_MG_4Hz_simplified.xlsx")

#different body points
ax1 = df.plot(kind='scatter', x='xsnout', y='ysnout', color='r', label='snout')    
ax2 = df.plot(kind='scatter', x='xMLA', y='yMLA', color='g', ax=ax1)
```

How would I specify just a single row instead of plotting the whole dataset? And is there anyway to connect the coordinates of a single row with a line?

Thank you and any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

> How would I specify just a single row instead of plotting the whole dataset?

To do this you can slice your dataframe. There's a large variety of ways of doing this and they'll depend on exactly what you're trying to do. For instance, you can use `df.iloc[]` to specify which rows you want. This is short for `index locator`. Note the brackets! If you want to specify your rows by their row index (and same for columns), you have to use `.loc[]`. For example, the plot with the original data you provided is:

[image]

Slicing the dataframe with `iloc`:

```py
ax1 = df.iloc[2:5, :].plot(kind='scatter', x='xsnout', y='ysnout', color='r', label='snout')
ax2 = df.iloc[2:5, :].plot(kind='scatter', x='xMLA', y='yMLA', color='g', ax=ax1)
```

Gives you this:

[image]

If you specify something like this, you get only a single line:

```py
df.iloc[1:2, :]
```

> And is there anyway to connect the coordinates of a single row with a line?

What exactly do you mean by this? You want to connect the points `(xsnout, ysnout)` with `(xMLA, yMLA)`? If that's so, then you can do it with this:

```py
plt.plot([df['xsnout'], df['xMLA']], [df['ysnout'], df['yMLA']])
```

[image]

Comment: That is extremely helpful, thank you so much. I plugged that into my dataset and the iloc worked perfectly. I also tried connecting the points and it worked but it connected the points from the entire dataset. Is there a way to do this with just the specified rows from iloc? below is my code

Comment: `ax1 = df.iloc[2:5, :].plot(kind='scatter', x='xsnout', y='ysnout', color='r', label='snout')`

Comment: `ax2 = df.iloc[2:5, :].plot(kind='scatter', x='xMLA', y='yMLA', color='g', ax=ax1)`

Comment: `plt.plot([df['xsnout'], df['xMLA'], [df['ysnout'], df['yMLA']])`

Comment: Apologize for the formatting, was having trouble fitting it all in one comment

Comment: Change the last command to this: `plt.plot([df.iloc[1:2]['xsnout'], df.iloc[1:2]['xMLA'], [df.iloc[1:2]['ysnout'], df.iloc[1:2]['yMLA']])`. Note I subdivided the dataframe then got the column I wanted. You could do it in a single command, but I tried preserving the code I showed you. The "cleaner" version is `plt.plot([df.loc[1, 'xsnout'], df.loc[1, 'xMLA']], [df.loc[1, 'ysnout'], df.loc[1, 'yMLA']])`. Replace `1` with the row number you want. Note `loc` behaves differently from `iloc`. If you play around you'll see what I mean.